# std::random_device constructor overhead

Tags: c++, random

From many sources in the net, it is suggested the use of `random_device` to produce random numbers. All of the code instantiate `random_device`, applies the proper `random_engine` or distribution, and makes use of it.
I'm wondering, what is the overhead of such pattern?
Instantiating the `random_device` will require the opening of `/dev/urandom` on linux, so the overhead may be heavier than it seems to appear from that sources.
Shouldn't be recommended of a monostate/singleton pattern for this instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How often are you creating random number engines that this matters?

Comment: Nothing prevents the constructors from accessing singletons behind the scenes. In any event, without evidence of a problem in a particular use case (e.g. performance measurement and profiling shows the creation of `random_device` and application of the distribution is a performance hotspot, that causes a particular program to not meet its requirements) then that sort of thing qualifies as premature optimisation. As a rough rule, if they haven't done thorough testing/profiling, programmers tend to over-estimate the impacts of such things, and over-estimate their ability to optimise their code.

Comment: Not very often, specifically. But if widespread in different context and different parts of the code, it seems to me that's may be an issue. I suspect it would be a good idea to instantiate a monostate object with `random_device` and `random_engine` and use it instead.

Comment: I've only seen suggestion to seed a pseudo-random bit generator (e.g. `mt19937`) once with `random_device` and use that generator all over the program. I wonder where it's suggested to directly use `random_device` for random number generation.

Comment: @HappyCactus that would cause all kinds of havoc in combination with `fork`

Comment: @cpplearner, no: but all the snippets I've found sofar instantiate a generator (`mt19937`) with a seed taken from a new instance of `random_device`. Nowhere I've seen they remark the possible overhead of this instantiation. From this comes my question.

Comment: `random_device` is slow but you only need to instantiate it once (per thread) and use it once (per thread) to initialize your `thread_local` generator. The only time it would matter is if you created many generators, but you usually shouldn't. Use one generator and multiple distributions. Distributions are cheap to create.